# CSS issue - margin top - Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, joomla

On my [Joomla site](http://www.wellnessinfo.info) I have a problem with the margin-top only in Google Chrome. Firefox & IE are ok. There are 27 pixels, the menu is above. I use a theme from Yootheme (but they are not able to solve the problem).

If I enter this style:

```
ul.menu.menu-dropline {
  margin-top:27px;
}
```

Google Chrome version is ok; but not Firefox & IE anymore.

Unfortunately I am not the CSS profi - hopefully you can help.

Kind regards
winfo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found these lines in your CSS code. Probably they cause the difference in behavior between FF and Webkit browsers.

```
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
-webkit-padding-start: 40px;
```

Quick solution:
Add the following to your CSS code.

```
ul.menu.menu-dropline {
    -webkit-margin-before: 27px;
}
```

Comment: Thx - this works for me fine! This CSS code is inserted from the template company (Yootheme); so it would be needed for some things.. Really: many thx for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

The code is a bit strange. You have a few things that doesn't make much sense.

You have on your `nav` wrapper `#menubar` a `margin-top` set for 27 pixels on *custom.css* then in the same file, another negative `margin-top` value for your `nav` element of -20 pixels.

You should **remove** those two **attributes and/or rules**:

```
#menu {
  margin-top: -20px;
}

#headerbar + #menubar {
  margin-top: -27px;
}
```

Comment: Thx pzin for your answer. I tried the tip from kdani, which works perfectly. If I remove this 2 attributes, the margin on menu would be higher (than it should be...) - thx for your help!