# How to set margin-top for Chrome browser only?

Tags: css

How to set margin-top for Chrome browser only? It looks like there's no `-webkit-margin-top` attribute in CSS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16118039/5859184 I think this answers it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 13):

Hmm that should work, unfortunately i can't comment, but try this

```
-webkit-margin-before: 100px;
```

That might fix the problem.

Comment: 1+ - `-webkit-margin-before` for top, `-webkit-margin-end` for right, `-webkit-margin-after` for bottom, and `-webkit-margin-start` for left.

Comment: Keep it mind that it will also affect all others webkit-based browsers, not only Chrome.

Comment: This is working in safari too, not only in chrome

Answer (score 1):

You can always do browser recognition in JS and then apply different base classes for different browsers. Also, this will make you happier when you look at your code in a year or two, rather than using CSS hacks which may or may not exist at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You can't check only 'chrome' on the CSS.
prefix '-webkit-' have many browsers that chrome, safari even the newest opera.
so you have to use the 'user agent'.
ex.

```js
$(function(){
 
 var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
 if (userAgent.indexOf("chrome") != -1){
  $('html').addClass('chrome');
 }
 
});
```

```css
.myEl{
 background: pink;
}

html.chrome .myEl{
 margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myEl">test</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but I agree with @Shomz. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you only want a margin in Chrome? If you're trying to correct some other issue that only occurs in Chrome, it's often that you've set some other property incorrectly (e.g. absolute top positioning when you don't need it).

In other words, what other behavior are you seeing that would make you want to consider this option?

Comment: There are plenty and plenty of things. CSS is something that almost has a mind of its own.....I have a similar problem, which I won't dare to explain here, because it is very detailed. So I can make the question for it instead.

Comment: i also had a very detailed problem like @VladimirDespotovic. My top margin in Chrome would just not be the same as the one in Firefox, resulting in uneven divs in both browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The best scripts to handle this situation, using UA to determine whether it is chrome browser